# How to Address Ambiguity in Past-Perfect Clauses with Unclear Temporal Context

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

**UPDATE:** The question has been edited to make the compared examples more consistent with each other.

> [1] Beverly felt a relief that was similar to the relief she **had felt** *when* the bathroom **was** clean again.

> [2] He saw the flickering of doubled vision, but the movements of violence **had receded** *as* the orange flecks **left** the Honored Matre's eyes.

Consider the above examples (1 and 2). These follow a past-perfect matrix clause with a simple-past subordinate clause introduced by the temporal prepositions 'when' and 'as.'

> [3] Benjavier opened the door a crack, only to have it shoved open all the way by a stiff arm from Locke, who called up some of the manner **he'd used** *when* **he'd lectured** Don Salvara as a "Midnighter".

> [4] Kyoshi's confidence **had vanished** *as* **she'd struggled** with Rangi's injury.

Now consider this second group of examples (3 and 4). These use a past-perfect matrix clause followed by a past-perfect subordinate clause introduced by the prepositions 'when' and 'as.'

In the subordinate clauses of all four of these examples, taken from traditionally published books, the author is referring to a time in the past before the current time of the book, regardless of whether they use the past-perfect 'had' or not.

Having read quite a few threads on this site talking about the use of past perfect, I'm still unsure whether I should follow the structure of the first group of examples (1 and 2) or the second (3 and 4).

It's been said that the past perfect is not *required* so long as the temporal shift is apparent, either through a temporal adjunct (such as 'the day before' or 'before he left') or implied context. We could argue that the contextual condition has been met in the subordinate clauses of 1 and 2, but I'd like to compare them to my next example (5).

> [5] M'Lord **had returned** *when* I **arrived** last night.

This is taken from another published work, and it follows the same grammatical pattern as examples 1 and 2. However, the meaning, as I understand it, can be construed in two different ways. First, the lord returned at the moment when 'I' arrived. This follows the same logic as examples 1 and 2. Second (in my opinion, the most logical interpretation), the lord returned before 'I' arrived.

That said, how can we justify omitting 'had' in examples 1 and 2? Is it a simple case of presumption? Assuming that the reader will follow the writer's logic? There's nothing to say that a reader couldn't interpret example 1 as 'Beverly felt the relief before the bathroom was clean.' Likewise, for example 2, this could be interpreted as 'the movements of violence receded before the orange flecks were leaving the Honored Matre's eyes.'

Compared to the usage of 'before' and 'after,' which I have seen discussed frequently in reference to omitting the past perfect, temporal prepositions such as 'when,' 'while,' and 'as' are far easier to misinterpret.

Comment: I'm not big on terminology, but apparently [*A matrix clause is a clause that structurally surrounds an embedded clause.*](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Matrix_clause) The example in the link is *The man **that the child kicked in the shins** winced in pain*, where the highlighted element is a "matrix clause". Your first example happens to include the word ***that***, but I can't for the life of me see any similarity between the structure of your sentence and the one in my link. I think you misunderstand what a matrix clause is.

Comment: Native speakers would be unlikely to repeat the Perfect verb form as in your examples #3 and #4. It's not *necessary*, so most writers (and practically *all* speakers) would switch to Simple Past after the first Past Perfect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: I would understand (5) to mean that his lordship had already returned and (1) that the old man was already dead.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps I am misinterpreting. The first example is an outlier in that it is a very specific type of idiomatic clause, beginning with 'If only.' However, I would argue it is a matrix clause because it contains 'when my Duke was born,' which is a subordinate clause and a temporal adjunct in the clause structure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you could point me to a specific section where it addresses this ambiguity, I'd be happy to accept this as duplicate. I've looked through it and can't find reference to this. It talks about 'after' and 'before,' but I can't find any issues with those prepositions resembling the ambiguity I'm discussing.

Comment: Re your *There's nothing to say that a reader couldn't interpret example 1 as 'the old man was dead before the Duke was born.'* I think that's nonsense. Pragmatically, we would assume the old man died ***after*** (not ***before***) Duke's birth, but it's the word ***when*** rather than the verb forms that "allows" your perverse interpretation. To avoid the (hypothetical, inconsequential) ambiguity, change ***when*** to ***before*** or ***after*** as required.

Comment: Note that your example #5 *(M'Lord **had** returned when I arrived last night)* uses Past Perfect to explicitly force ***when*** to be interpreted as meaning ***before***, but Simple Past + ***when*** would mean exactly the same: *M'Lord returned **before** I arrived last night*. It's just that the Simple Past draws more attention to m'Lord's earlier return, where Past Perfect focuses more on the later state of affairs when I arrived.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you like to write an answer? These are very valuable insights, so if you have the time to put them into a singular explanation, that would be very appreciated. I would perhaps like to hear an alternative perspective before accepting it, but that doesn't mean it's not useful. I'm still going through some of the threads listed in the link you provided, but none of them have dived into this specifically so far.

Comment: Your first interpretation of #5 *(the lord returned **at the moment when** I arrived)* isn't exactly justifiable. It's an "unlikely" reading, as a general principle - but if that was the *intended* sense, a competent writer would probably convey it more explicitly: *M'Lord had returned **at the same time as** I [had] arrived last night.* But a competent writer probably wouldn't pointlessly include the Perfect verb form there anyway.

Comment: @MJAda Your sentence [1] doesn't belong in this list because it has *irrealis* mood, where the others have *realis* mood. Irrealis mood **uses past perfect in place of simple past** to indicate it's unreal, so that example is not comparable to the others. In sentence [1], the meaning is "*That old man **didn't die** when my Duke was born*" (simple past). Please replace or remove that sentence so we're comparing apples with apples.

Comment: What ambiguity??

Comment: @Lambie The question specifically relates to the omission (or lack thereof) of 'had' and the potential ambiguities arising from that. Example 5 illustrates a context in which the temporal interpretation is different from examples 1 and 2 despite all three sharing the same structure (with 'had' not being included in the subordinate clause). Though not easy to misinterpret, I would like to know why the omission is justifiable in 1 and 2 when the authors of 3 and 4 have perceived the inclusion of 'had' to be necessary. 'Ambiguity' is very debatable, I admit, but the syntactical question is there.

Comment: Ambiguity is not the right word. I think you should actually post sentences, one above the other that show that supposed ambiguity.// Beverly felt a relief that was similar to the relief she had felt when the bathroom was clean again. versus Beverly felt relief [no a] before the bathroom was clean again. Those are just **two different sentences**. All your sentences have a past perfect **preceded by** by a simple past. In 4, you have to change **had struggled** to struggled to make it standard grammar.

Comment: 5) is fine and *follows the rule*: past perfect shows an action that occurs **prior to** an action in the simple past:  M'Lord **had returned** when I **arrived** last night.

Comment: I think my phrasing of the question has detracted from what I'm actually trying to find out. It's not so much that I think there's any ambiguity, but rather I'm wondering why there's no risk of that on the basis that examples 3 and 4 maintain the past perfect for all verbs taking place before the time of orientation. A better question would perhaps be: When can we safely omit 'had' in past-perfect clauses introduced by the prepositions 'when,' 'as,' and 'while'?

Comment: Please reread my comments. I have answered your question and fixed 5) so it will work. He arrived when I had finished. versus He arrived when I finished. This is about the **meaning** you want to give an utterance. The had + past participle ALWAYS precedes something in the simple past or continuous, either literally or implied.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but are you saying 3 and 4 are the outliers? Are they non-standard? I'm aware that the past-perfect clauses are anterior to the past simple that contextualises them. It is everything contained within the past-perfect matrix clause that makes me ask whether the extra 'had' within a clause intended to specify time is needed. It could be an answer as simple as, 'it's a choice,' which is the case with 'had' in sentences with 'before' and 'after.' The amount of information here has made it hard to fully dissect, so forgive me if I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: There is nothing that precludes two past perfects: After they arrived, I had washed and dried the dishes. After I had washed and dried the dishes, they had arrived. This before and after thing is just a no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETA: *Improved concision based on OP comment:*

> Though it doesn't dive into the comparisons I have highlighted, the
> answer I was looking for is conveyed here: [Past simple or past
> perfect in a subordinate clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27082/178564)
> -- *OP from the comments*

*From the linked [ELL answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27082/178564)*:

> Once the 'background' anteriority of waiting has been established, the
> narrator has a choice of constructions for continuing the … narrative.
>
> There is no “rule” to say that one choice is the better than the
> other. The difference is one of focus:
>
> - with pasts, the focus is on the prior events as narrative
> - with perfects, the focus is on the prior events as explanation

When applicable:
**Rule:** Past perfect shows an action that occurs ***prior to*** an action in the **simple past** *([EF](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/): Offers a less succinct description)*.

If the simple past breaks the rule that informs the appropriate order of occurrence  as described, in this rule, then it is necessary to use care when choosing the correct tense.

### Case Wet Boyfriend

The example sentence:

> After an hour my boyfriend arrived! His clothes were soaking wet and he was covered in mud.
> Apparently, he *had been waiting* at a bus stop,
> when a car *had driven* straight through a puddle
> and *had splashed* him from head to toe.

Although it does not follow the if-then structure of the examples in the original question, nevertheless its expression, in the form of a compound sentence, provides a good opportunity to isolate contextual clues that can guide a reader to a writer’s intention. The use of an irregular verb heightens the contrast between using a past perfect phrase and a simple past under the circumstances of analyzing an ordered series.

Establishment of anteriority:

- *Apparently, he **had been waiting** at a bus stop*

*When* introduces a series of subsequent events executed by a car:

- A) *had driven* straight through a puddle
- B) *had splashed* him from head to toe

The structure of the sentence dictates that subsequent to the action defined by *when*, first A then B occurred. Changing the order of A and B requires a change in temporal identifiers to describe the series of events as they occurred in the example.

*Apparently, he **had been waiting** at a bus stop, when a car*:

1. ***had driven*** straight through a puddle and ***had splashed*** him from head to toe.
2. **drove** straight through a puddle and **splashed** him from head to toe.
3. ***had driven*** straight through a puddle and **splashed** him from head to toe.
4. **drove** straight through a puddle and ***had splashed*** him from head to toe.

The rule that governs our understanding of the description of a past perfect event, dictates that all events must occur subsequent to *the boyfriend waiting at a bus stop*.

*Example* 1: explains the series of events that occurred after the event of the *when* clause consistently with little or no emphasis on any one event.

*Example* 2: narrates the latter events of the series using the simple past, which serves to off-set these events with somewhat equal importance over the event of the *when* clause.

*Example* 3: This mixed tense sentence aligns with the rule that the past perfect event must express an action that occurs prior to the action in the simple past. Choosing this structure, will allow the reader to interpret the prior events (presented in the past perfect) as context in the service of bringing focus to the event written in the simple past: *splashed him from head to toe*.

*Example* 4: This sentence breaks the rule that the past perfect must express an action that occurs prior to the action in the simple past. In this series of events, the *drove* inappropriately happens before  the *had splashed* event, thus running afoul of the rule. Readers might receive this sentence anywhere in the range from awkward to wrong.

> It's been said that the past perfect is not required so long as the temporal shift is apparent, either through a temporal adjunct (such as 'the day before' or 'before he left') or implied context.

Perhaps, it may be easier to conceptualize that the past perfect is only *required* when the simple past breaks the rules of order of occurrence for the past perfect/simple past structure, as in Example 4. If it is grammatical for the simple past to occupy a place in the construction of a sentence, then that it can be used at any time based on the intention of the writer.

### Case m'Lord

from the Original Question:

> This is taken from another published work…the meaning, as I understand
> it, can be construed in two different ways. First, the lord returned
> at the moment when 'I' arrived...Second (in my opinion, the most
> logical interpretation), the lord returned before 'I' arrived.
>
> *M'Lord **had returned** when I **arrived** last night.*

Examine the inverse:

- When I *arrived* last night, m’Lord *had returned*.
- When I *arrived* last night, m’Lord *returned*.

This inversion removes some of the ambiguity by exposing the nuances of what each sentence actually conveys. *Had returned* and *returned* are two distinct concepts when set in opposition to *arrived.*

1. M’Lord had returned when I arrived last night.
2. M’Lord returned when I arrived last night

Of the two possible interpretations that are listed in the question:

> A. *the lord returned at the moment when 'I' arrived*
> B. *the lord returned before 'I' arrived*

Examining them in isolation shows us that sentence 1 better supports the B interpretation; the A interpretation is more clearly expressed in sentence 2. This example shows that the choice between past perfect/simple past constructions can unexpectedly alter the meaning by a more significant degree based on their relation to each other. In this case, it appears that the connotations of arrived/returned may interfere with a straightforward interpretation of events.

### Case Style

> Having read quite a few threads on this site talking about the use of
> past perfect, I'm still unsure whether I should follow the structure
> of the first group of examples (1 and 2) or the second (3 and 4).
>
> - (1 and 2) These follow a past perfect matrix clause with a simple-past subordinate clause introduced by the temporal prepositions
>   'when' and 'as.'
> - (3 and 4)These use a past perfect matrix clause followed by a past perfect subordinate clause introduced by the prepositions 'when' and
>   'as.'

(1 and 2): Might read more dynamic
(3 and 4): Might read more neutral

Comment: To add to your answer, I would like to link to a similar question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27082/past-simple-or-past-perfect-in-a-subordinate-clause. Though it doesn't dive into the comparisons I have highlighted, the answer I was looking for is conveyed here. 'Once the "background" anteriority ... has been established, the narrator has a choice of constructions for continuing the narrative ....' The reason there is no ambiguity in examples 1 and 2 is because anteriority has been clearly established, and the narrator has chosen to continue with past simple.

Comment: I'm returning to this answer to add some knowledge from CGEL (5.4, p.146). Huddleston and Pullum provide a logical outline for the difference between Example 1 and 5. Tr[2] < To[2]/Tr[1] < To[1]. Tr refers to 'referred time,' and they highlight that there are two different focuses for the past perfect: the first on Tr[1] (this is the case in Example 5), the second on Tr[2] (this is the case in Example 1). Effectively Tr[1] is focused on the past tense, while Tr[2] is focused on the past perfect. To answer my own question, context dictates the focus, preventing ambiguity.